# Access SQL: syntax error in join statement

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I'm trying to execute a SQL statement, but I get an error that says there's a syntax error in the join.

I'm executing the following query:

```
SELECT 
    T.Omschrijving as Team, P.Beschrijving AS Proces, 
    Round(Sum(P.Aantal), 2) AS Prognose, P.Maand AS PrognoseMaand, 
    P.jaar, A.Omschrijving AS Fonds 
FROM 
    tblPrognose AS P, tblTeam AS T, tblAfdeling AS A 
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT 
         RL.Omschrijving, I.TEAMID, I.PROCESOMS, 
         SUM(NORMUREN_I) AS Instroom, I.Maand, I.Jaar
     FROM 
         tblInstroom AS I 
     LEFT JOIN 
         (SELECT 
              T.Omschrijving, R.GPSTeam, R.Procesoms 
          FROM 
              tblRollen AS R, tblTeam AS T 
          WHERE 
              T.TeamID = R.TeamID) AS RL ON (I.TEAMID = RL.GPSTEAM AND I.PROCESOMS = RL.PROCESOMS)
     GROUP BY 
         I.TEAMID, I.Procesoms, I.maand, I.jaar, RL.Omschrijving) AS tblR ON (tblR.Omschrijving = T.Omschrijving) AND (tblR.Procesoms = P.Beschrijving) AND (tblR.Maand = P.Maand) AND (tblR.jaar = P.jaar) 
WHERE 
    P.KPI = 'Instroom' 
    AND P.Maand BETWEEN Month(P.Datum_vanaf) AND Month(P.Datum_tot) 
    AND P.jaar BETWEEN year(P.Datum_vanaf) AND year(P.Datum_tot) 
    AND P.TeamID = T.TeamID 
    AND A.AfdelingID = T.AfdelingID 
    AND NOT Nz(P.Beschrijving, '') = '' 
GROUP BY 
    T.Omschrijving, P.Maand, P.jaar, P.Beschrijving, A.Omschrijving
```

I have tested if the error is within the JOINs but it isn't. If I execute the SELECTs seperately they work just fine and give me the correct results.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause (unless you intend a `CROSS JOIN`).

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**25 years** ago!) and its use is discouraged